# Override a builtin command with cabbrev

Tags: vim, viml

I'm trying to override 'w' in vim so it would call an external program and filter the buffer instead of writing to a file. There are very good examples across the internet about how to do that. I tried one from vim.wikia.com, but vim always complains with `E488: Trailing characters`. This is the command in my vimrc:

```
cabbrev w <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'W' : 'w')<CR>
```

I'm not very familiar with vim script. I tried removing `<CR>` from the end of the line with no luck.

**UPDATE**

Since I want to run vim as customized as possible I run it with the `-u` flag. I noticed that vim behaves differently when using that flag compared to running it without it

With the `-u` flag the expanded abbreviation is what needs to be evaluated as code.
[image]

Without the flag, the abbreviation is what it is intended to be (here I enter the cabbrev rule from vim's prompt)
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. When I run it and then try to run `:w`, it is remapped to `W`, which causes a completely unrelated error. Have you tried this with no `.vimrc`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just tried to enter to command from vim itself. I still get `E488: Trailing characters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the `-u` flag vim's man page says this:

> -u {vimrc}  Use  the  commands in the file {vimrc} for
>   initializations.  All the other initializations
>                are skipped.  Use this to edit a special kind of files.  It can also be used to  skip  all
>                initializations by giving the name "NONE".  See ":help initialization" within vim for more
>                details.

Apparently when this flag is used the initialization from 
vim /etc/vimrc is not performed and there I found this option:

```
set nocompatible
```

vim's help about **compatible** option:

> This option has the effect of making Vim either more Vi-compatible, or
>   make Vim behave in a more useful way. This is a special kind of
>   option, because when it's set or reset, other options are also changed
>   as a side effect.  CAREFUL: Setting or resetting this option can have
>   a lot of unexpected effects: Mappings are interpreted in another way,
>   undo behaves differently, etc.  If you set this option in your vimrc
>   file, you should probably put it at the very start.
>
> ...
>
> When a **vimrc** or **gvimrc** file is found while Vim is starting up, 
>   this option is switched off, and all options that have not been 
>   modified will be set to the Vim defaults.  Effectively, this means 
>   that when a **vimrc** or **gvimrc** file exists, Vim will use the Vim 
>   defaults, otherwise it will use the Vi defaults.  (Note: This doesn't 
>   happen for the system-wide vimrc or gvimrc file, *nor for a file given 
>   with the **-u** argument*).

`set nocompatible` makes the cabbrev syntax from the question work